# issue performing an INSERT statement with mysql_query() PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

basically I am trying to implement a function in one of my `PHP` classes that makes an entry into a junction table for a `many to many` relationship.

This is the method here:

```
public function setTags($value, $id){
    global $db;
    $tags = $value;
    $query .= "DELETE FROM directorycolumntags 
               WHERE directorycolumn_id = $id; ";
    foreach($tags as $tag){
    $query .= "INSERT INTO directorycolumntags (directorycolumn_id, tag_id)
               VALUES (".$id.",".$tag.");";
    }   
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

The `SQL` is produces works fine, as I've echoed it and manually executed it via `phpMyAdmin`. However, If I leave it as above, the data is never inserted. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

This is the `sql` it is generating which works fine when I type it manually in:

```
DELETE FROM directorycolumntags WHERE directorycolumn_id = 178; 
INSERT INTO directorycolumntags (directorycolumn_id, tag_id) VALUES (178,29);
INSERT INTO directorycolumntags (directorycolumn_id, tag_id) VALUES (178,30);
INSERT INTO directorycolumntags (directorycolumn_id, tag_id) VALUES (178,32);
```

Comment: `mysql_query` does only one statement at a time, it is also deprecated

Comment: nope, you can just concatenate statements and then execute them, its not supported in that API, and stop using that.

Comment: multiple queries can't be done using the ***deprecated*** `mysql` extension. You can use `mysqli`, but you'd be better of deleting, and then using a prepared statement to insert your tags one by one (perhaps in a transaction). Learn the current DB extensions (`mysqli` or `PDO`). PS: `global` is _evil_

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Out of curiosity, if the original application was built with the `mysql` extension and I'm just concerned with patching the existing functionality is it safe to use the deprecated extension, until I'm in a position to upgrade the entire app itself?

Comment: @Javacadabra: Using the deprecated extension is _not_ safe. Since PHP 5.5, each `mysql_*` function call will result in a `E_DEPRECATED` notice being issued, clogging the logs. The extension itself is scheduled for removal in the future, though no date has been set. You can quite easily update your code to the newer extensions. I prefer `PDO`, for its clean API and it being, all things considered, easy to learn (check my answer, it contains a full example of how you can do what you're trying to do using PDO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old, unsafe, deprecated `mysql_*` extension ***never*** supported multiple queries. You *could*, conceivably do this using the `mysql` replacement extension: `mysqli_*`, which has [the `mysqli_multi_query` function](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).
Personally, I'd not use this approach, though. I'd do what most devs would do: use a prepared statement in a transaction to execute each query safely, and commit the results on success, or rollback on failure:

```
$db = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db;charset=utf8',
    'user',
    'pass',
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
);
try
{
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM tbl WHERE field = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl (field1, field2) VALUES (:field1, :field2)');
    foreach ($tags as $tag)
    {
        $stmt->execute(
            array(
                ':field1' => $id,
                ':field2' => $tag
            )
        );
        $stmt->closeCursor();//<-- optional for MySQL
    }
    $db->commit();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $db->rollBack();
    echo 'Something went wrong: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

Going slightly off-topic: You really ought to consider using type-hints. From your code, it's clear that `$values` is expected to be an array. A type-hint can ensure that the value being passed is in fact an array. You should also get rid of that ugly `global $db;`, and instead pass the connection as an argument, too. That's why I'd strongly suggest you change your function's signature from:

```
public function setTags($value, $id){
```

To:

```
public function setTags(PDO $db, array $value, $id)
{
}
```

That way, debugging gets a lot easier:

```
$instance->setTags(123, 123);//in your current code will not fail immediately
$instance->setTags($db, [123], 123);//in my suggestion works but...
$instance->setTags([123], null, '');// fails with a message saying argument 1 instance of PDO expected
```

Comment: Brilliant Answer, will do, thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: @Javacadabra: You're welcome, just so you know: if you do decide to refactor the code, switching to either `PDO` or `mysqli`, you can post your first attempt [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some code-review. That way, you'll know if you're going about things the right way

Comment: Oh cool, That's an awesome site, I Wasn't aware of it's existence, will do, much appreciated.

Comment: @Javacadabra: You're welcome. I can't make promises, but I'll try to review your code if you decide to post it. CR is a great site, with a smaller, but more supportive community than SO, so it's definitely worth a try. It still says _"beta"_, but if you check the meta, you'll see that CR has now officially graduated, and will become a permanent SE site. Oh, and thank _you_ for actually being willing to listen, and learn the new DB extensions. +1 for being reasonable, and willing to put in the work

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.php.net/mysql_query says:

```
mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier
```

If you can use mysqli perhaps this interest you: [mysqli.multi-query](http://docs.php.net/mysqli.multi-query)

```
Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not run multiple quires using mysql_query, try to modify your function like this. It would be better if you use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql because soon it will deprecated and it would not work on newer version of php

```
public function setTags($value, $id){
    global $db;
    $tags = $value;
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM directorycolumntags WHERE directorycolumn_id = $id");
    foreach($tags as $tag){
        mysql_query("INSERT into directorycolumntags (directorycolumn_id, tag_id) VALUES (".$id.",".$tag.")");
    }   
}
```